# Trying to append a data in webdhfs i receive error message as follows

Tags: hdfs, webhdfs

RecoveryInProgressException

later I tried to append once again and this time I received this message
Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[172.17.0.2:50010], original=[172.17.0.2:50010]). The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration."}

Note I am using only node1 in ambari which is namenode and datanode.
Please let me know how can i recover from this failure and continue with appending the file?

Comment: Is your datanode running and has sufficient disk space?

Comment: Yes data node is running and it has sufficient disk space